# Get rid of the number on some of the edges

Tags: tikz-trees

How can I get rid of the circled marked 0 in red on the edge?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{el style/.style={midway, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=+1pt, auto=right}}
\forestset{angled/.style={
    content/.expanded={\noexpand\textless\forestov{content}\noexpand\textgreater}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={parent anchor=south},
  where n children={0}{tier=word}{
    if={n==1}{% n == 1 means first child
      edge label={node[el style]{0}}
    }{
      edge label={node[el style, swap]{1}}
    }
  }
%
[2n+4 [n [$\bar{1}$ [0]]]
      [n+4 [n [$\bar{0}$ [10]]]   
           [4 [1 [d [110]]]   
              [3 [1 [c [1110]]] 
                 [2 [1 [b[11110] ] ]
                    [1 [a [11111] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop only on the nodes that have 2 children:

```
  where n children={0}{tier=word}{},
  where n children={2}{
    for children={
      if={n==1}{% n == 1 means first child
          edge label={node[el style]{0}}
      }{
        edge label={node[el style, swap]{1}}
      }
    }
  }{},
```

Comment: but this solution will remove all edge's ZERO and not only the red marked one!

Comment: edit: sorry my mistake. It was checking the num of children to decide the parent's edge label. Now it should work

Comment: it works now thanks. Do you know how can I center the whole tree in my page?

Comment: the usual `\begin{center}` environment should do just fine (use `\centering` if in a figure to avoid extra vertical space). If you have problems with that post another question